# how to check status of process executed using Desktop in java

Tags: java

I am making a Java program that starts a third party application

```
Desktop dsktp=Desktop.getDesktop();
dsktp.open(new File("C:\\abcd.exe"));
```

It is starting the program successfully.
Now I want to enable the next button only when this process is completed (or closed or forcefully terminated).
How can I get status if this process has ended or not?

Comment: Better use Process from Java

Comment: didn't found any way to do this method...
Process is asking "Program through which file is to be opened" , "file path" as argument

Comment: You can’t, Desktop doesn’t provide any means to connect with the running process. As already stated, it’s better to use `Process`, preferably using `ProcessBuilder` - plenty of examples available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `ProcessBuilder` instead and also take an `Interface` based approach. This is going to be long; but it should help you to understand the way this problem should be addressed.

Let's define our interface first-

```
public interface ProcessEventListener {
    public void onComplete(Process process);
}
```

Now for better modularity let's create a `ProcessManager` class-

```
public class ProcessManager extends Thread {
    private ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
    private Process process;
    private List<ProcessEventListener> processEventListeners = new ArrayList<ProcessEventListener>();

    public ProcessManager(String externalProcessPath, List<String> args) {
        args.add(0, externalProcessPath);
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    }

    public ProcessManager(String externalProcessPath) {
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(externalProcessPath);
    }

    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            process = processBuilder.start();
            // wait until the process is completed
            process.waitFor(); 
            // let the listeners know since the process is completed
            for (ProcessEventListener listener : processEventListeners) {
                listener.onComplete(process);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    public void addProcessEventListener(ProcessEventListener processEventListener) {
        processEventListeners.add(processEventListener);
    }

    public void removeAllListeners() {
        processEventListeners.clear();
    }
}
```

Let's define a class that will implement the interface-

```
public class NextActionInitiator implements ProcessEventListener {
    public void onComplete(Process process) {
       // your workflow for next button action or enabling the button or
       // whatever; should go here.
    }
}
```

Using all these together is straightforward.

```
// provide the process manager an absolute path of your executable; you 
// can also pass arguments as an ArrayList as second parameter.
// ...new ProcessManager("\absolute\path\of\your\exe", argList);
ProcessManager pManager = new ProcessManager("\absolute\path\of\your\exe");
NextActionInitiator nextActionInitiator = new NextActionInitiator();
pManager.addProcessEventListener(nextActionInitiator);
pManager.start();
```

The `onComplete` method defined in `NextActionInitiator` should only be fired once the process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

So better use `Process` and `ProcessBuilder` :

```
String[] args = {"C:\\abcd.exe"};
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    pb = pb.redirectErrorStream(true);                // put error out with normal out

    Process p = pb.start();       
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String str; 
    while (( str= br.readLine()) != null) { 
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

For some programs you'll need to add `p.waitFor();` after the start, depend on how they are built